# How do I find what program is keeping the taskbar from auto-hiding?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notifications

The name says it all. Taskbar is set to auto-hide, taskbar does not auto-hide, obviously, I want it to auto-hide. Some program is keeping it from doing that. Sometimes I find the culprit quickly if the developer made something like the icon or app flash but sometimes I search for a while before I find it.

(And no, [this](https://superuser.com/a/341408/239830), [this](https://superuser.com/a/473209/239830) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/321221/239830) are not answers to "what program," they are cop-outs when you can't fix the problem. I already have an autohotkey to kill and restart Explorer but it's annoying.)

Bonus points if you know the Windows message to trap to prevent a program from doing it because my next step is creating an open-source app that blocks it and auto-generates an email to the developer every time it happens.

---

Edit: I'm presently looking at poking around with [the SHAppBarMessage function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shappbarmessage) when I get time so if anyone has already tried that, a success/fail report could save me time.

---

**Edit 2**:

*Still,* this ridiculously persistent problem keeps popping up and sticking around after all these years. My current favorite workaround is pinning an Explorer re-launcher to the taskbar:

1. Create a bat file containing `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer`
   [image: Create bat file]
2. Right click the bat and create a shortcut to it
3. Right click the shortcut and edit it so that instead of `{path to blahblah.bat}`, it has `cmd \c "{path to blahblah.bat}"`  *... (this is to circumvent Microsoft protecting you from putting what you want on the taskbar because they think you're dumb)*
   [image: Edit shortcut]
4. Drag your fancy new shortcut to the taskbar
   [image: Winning Workaround]

Comment: btw you can change the target of that shortcut to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer.exe` (optional)

Answer (score 0):

From this article: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/04/29/windows-10-taskbar-not-hiding-here-is-the-fix/

The idea is to discover the underlying app that wants attention.  Some apps or background apps do not have an icon displayed, therefore no indication is visible.

Solution: Enable all icons for a short time to see the icon that is wanting attention.

Quote:
Start by opening the Taskbar preferences again. This is done with the keyboard shortcut Windows-I, and navigating to Personalization > Taskbar in the Settings application.

Locate and click on "select which icons appear on the taskbar" under notification area.

[Select-icons-taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPPa1.png)

I recommend that you check the "always show all icons in the notification area". The reason for that is that you get a good overview of all icons, and can identify the culprit easily this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a utility called focus-monitor.exe -- I forget where I downloaded it from, unfortunately, and it doesn't take any command-line options to give any information.  But it runs a steady output of the process name of any process stealing focus. I would imagine the program keeping your taskbar from autohiding would possibly be stealing focus.